# Is there a limit of wave function splitting?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse

It is possible to split the wave function (for example using a semi mirror like in Wheeler delayed choice experiment). I wonder what happens if we split it many times.

My "though experiment" would be to split a wave function in half, then each half is itself split in half, etc. until that each wave function are so small that it would be reduced to a point and at this time what would happen?

In other term, is it possible to split the wave function indefinitely or is there a limit that would provoke the wave function to collapse? (or something else...)

As the splitting is exponential, It is certainly impossible to proceed to a real experiment like this and it probably remains as a though experiment but I wonder if the theory can predict something about this

Comment: This is just a guess, but wouldn't any interaction (which would be required for splitting) collapse the wave function?

Comment: No, by "splitting", I means that we give the wave 2 possible paths like what is done in the double slit experiment (with 2 slits) or in Wheeler delayed choice experiment (with semi mirrors)